# 1920x1080 being stretched as 4:3 after "apt upgrade"

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution

I'am having a problem with every distro that I try to use.
My monitor is 16:9 and supports 1920x1080 resolution, which I use perfectly on Windows and sometimes it works on Linux distros.

The problem is, the first time I make `apt upgrade` on a recently Linux installation, my screen becomes a stretched 1920x1080, like a 4:3 without fitting the whole monitor. See the images below.

[image: Picture of monitor]

[image: Print of Display Settings on Solus OS] (The same occurs to every distro)

I tried to reinstall and reconfigure Xorg multiple times, made every possible change to the Xrandr Modeline, downloaded every NVidia driver available and don't know what to do anymore.

My GPU is: GTX 960

Please, if you have any idea on how to solve it, let me know. I shall be forever grateful.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: If the asker wants to use Ubuntu to solve this problem, then it's not off-topic.  Hi luanlqg: When using Ubuntu, please give us the full, unredacted output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` -- since by your theory, this is where your system breaks down.  Please add this information by using [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1269344/edit).  You can retain formatting and line breaks by putting four spaces in front of each line.

Comment: Hi luanlqg, the images show broken here, so if you can either upload them again or tell us for example the specific monitor you are using along with the additional information Nmath asked, that would help.